# Find the probability: Two points are selected randomly on a line of length L

Tags: probability, geometry, analytic-geometry

Please help me with this one.

Two points (B and C) are selected randomly on a line of length L. Find the probability that the segment BC has a length less than L / 4. It is assumed that the probability of a point falling on the segment is proportional to the length and does not depend on its location on the numerical axis OX.

Comment: It is a cute problem. What have you tried so far? Maybe you have learned about various probability models before?

Comment: It's a variant of this sort of problem (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952054/probability-of-two-people-meeting-within-60-mins-with-maximum-waiting-time-is-20), for which there are many other postings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wlog we can assume $L=1$ and $x,y$ are coordinates of $B$ and $C$ then $\Omega$ is $[0,1]^2$ and the event is set all of $(x,y)$ such that $|x-y|\leq {1\over 4}$. Drawing this set of points in the coordinate system you can see it has area $$1-\Big({3\over 4}\Big)^2= {7\over 16}$$ which is also the answer to your question.

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot, thank you so much for taking your time to help me!